# How to insert these multiple and single rows correctly in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application which consists of 2 pages. One of those pages generates a 3 letter Id for a session and it allows the user to type in a number of sessions they require in a textbox and the total marks required for the session also in a textbox.

When that page is submitted, it will then go onto the next page and whilst doing this it will insert those details in the database. Now at the moment if the user requires only 1 session, the the insert of the details into a database table works perfectly. Below is an example of this:

Example: If session is 'ABA', number of sessions is '1' and total marks is '20', then the row is inserted like this below in the Session DB table:

```
SessionId  TotalMarks

ABA         20
```

But the problem I want to encounter is below:

Lets say we have the same session ID 'ABA' and the total marks is still '20' but the difference is that the user wants the number of sessions to be 3, then I want the this to be inserted in the table row:

```
SessionId  TotalMarks

ABA1         20
ABA2         20
ABA3         20
```

As you can see as we have multiple sessions, it has included a number next to each session, ABA1 to indicate this is first session, ABA2 to indicate it is second session and ABA3 to indicate it is third session. As the user has stated the total marks is '20', then this is included for all of those session rows.

So my question is how can I get it so that if there is a multiple number of sessions, then add a number next to each sessionId and the total marks for all of those sessions? But if the user only wants 1 number of sessions, it still does the same as what it does currently which is display the 3 letter sessionId with NO number next to it?

Below is the INSERT VALUES code for inserting SessionId and TotalMarks in the Session Table:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Session (SessionId, TotalMarks)
VALUES
(' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['id'] ) . "',' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['textMarks'] ) . "')";

mysql_query($sql);
```

Below is the code of the form which contains the 3 letter SessionId, Number of Sessions Textbox and Total Marks Textbox:

```
     <form action="QandATable.php" method="post" id="sessionForm">

             <p><strong>1: Your Session ID: </strong><?php echo $id; ?></p>
             <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id; ?>' />

  <p><strong>2: Number of Sessions you Require:</strong> <input type="text" id="sessionNo" name="sessionNum"/></p>

    <p><strong>3: Total Marks: </strong><input type="text" id="txtMarks" name="textMarks" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not add an additional column "numberOfSessions" so that you can have ABA | 20 | 3 ?

Comment: Because if there is one session, then I don't want it to show ABA1 when selecting it from a drop down menu or something like that

Comment: I still don't see the problem. There won't be ABA1 in the database at all. If there is only one session with ABA, the row will look like this: ABA | 20 | 1, if there are 3, it will look like this: ABA | 20 | 3. There is no ABA1 or ABA3 in either case, so you can just display ABA in the drop down.

Comment: Yes but if it just say ABA and there are 3 sessions, if I want a class to take a different session to another class, how do they know which session to choose if it just says ABA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be what you need:

```
<?php

  // Reset the array
  $insert = array();

  // Iterate over the number of desired sessions and add the relevant INSERT VALUES
  for ($i = 1, $n = $_POST['sessionNum']; $i <= $n; ++$i)
  {
    $insert[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']) . $i . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['textMarks']) . "'";
  }

  // Create the SQL string
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `Session` (`SessionId`, `TotalMarks`) VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insert) . ")";

  // Perform the query
  mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: You are a genius, Thank you for your help, that has worked perfectly :)